# Character encoding issue when loading a div using jQuery.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding

I am loading a html page to a div using jquery AJAX load. The loaded page has german characters, and is not encoded correctly, while the german characters in the main page is displayed correctly. Somebody please help me with this issue.

### HTML Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-15"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
 url : 'startPage.html',
 dataType: 'text',
 contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
 success : function(data){
           $('#loadPage').html(data);
           }
 });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loadPage"></div>
<br />
Länge Länge
</body>
</html>
```

### code for startPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-15"/>
</head>
<body>
Loaded Content - Länge - (This text is not displayed correctly)
</body>
</html>
```

In This page I event tried adding the meta tags for iso encoding, still without any success. Please help

Answer (score 5):

```
 beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=iso-8859-15');
    },
```

Use this within your ajax function, or ajaxSetup();

Comment: For German Characters its ideal to use this characterset (charset=iso-8859-15) and not the UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure all your charset are declared the same way in order to display correctly. In example, you get:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-15"/>
```

While asking for:

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
```

Make sure you know which one you want and give the right charset.  The encoding of your .html, .php and .js documents is also a factor of errors.  If you'Re using notepad++ or any editors of code, make sure you encoded your files with the same charset you want them to display.  I suggest you "convert" your files so that you dont loose all special caracters you already put in there.

Comment: I am using "charset=iso-8859-15" for german characters, and i tried making both the same, but still without any success.... :-(